# Create new user with Membship class c# vs2017 community

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

its been a while since I last used the Membership class to create a new user account with vs2017 community. I've followed a tutorial from microsoft to the point where the code is:

MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(username, password, email, etc);

But the only option with the Membership class is

```
Membership.CreateHtmlTextWriterFromType
```

and if I were to create a 'new' instance of the Membership class there still is no option to create the user. Can some body please tell me whats going on here as I don't remember it been this difficult to do.

Thanks Mick.

Answer (score 0):

Funny enough I'm answering my own question so no votes please.
When using class normally I would declare it by adding "using System.Web.Security" at the top of the file, but for some reason when writing the syntax all the methods it would show is "CreateHtmlTextWriterFromType" which is not what I wanted. Whereas this worked.

```
System.Web.Security.MembershipUser user = System.Web.Security.Member.CreateUser("", "");
```

Go figure!